# I have unmatched rows from my fact table showing up unless I put a useless calculation in the values section of my pivot table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

I should begin by saying that I'm very new to Power Pivot and Power Query.

I have a dim table that contains work orders and a fact table that contains documents that are related to the work orders. There's a one-to-many relationship from the dim table to the fact table. I only want to display the status of the documents in the fact table in the pivot table along with some fields from the dim table.

I tried doing a one-to-many join and just displaying two fields (document number and document status) and it would show every value from the fact table for every item in the dim table that matched my filtering criteria.

I fixed this by having it count a column in the fact table. It quit showing unmatched rows, which is good, but I'm stuck with a column of useless information in the pivot table.

Is this the optimal way of handling unmatched rows from the fact table and, if so, is there an easy way to hide the calculated column that I don't need? Thanks in advance.

Addendum: I've attempted to create something that looks like the problem. The items in red are unmatched and coming from the fact table. Basically, every unique value from the fact table is showing up under each entry in the dim table.

I can fix this for just *one* fact table by adding a calculation to the values area. If I add a second fact table, it multiplies out of control. I hope this clears it up a little.

I'm apparently too new to post images yet.

[Facsimile of unmatched/repeating rows from the fact table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FQK9.png)

Comment: You ask isn't clear, could you share a snip of your pivot/visual and what you want or not want to see. Update your question above with the same.

Comment: @SamNseir I will see if I can get a screencap tomorrow. It'll be difficult since it's a work task. Thanks for the comment. I sometimes forget that it's easy for me to picture and not for everyone else.

Comment: @SamNseir I added an update. I hope it helps.

Comment: Select your table, and in the filter pane on the right, under `Filters on this visual`, try setting `Work Order #` is not blank, and see if that is what you are after.

Comment: @SamNseir excellent. I will try it tomorrow. Thanks!